# PHP Subtraction doesn't work

Tags: php

I have 2 variables:

```
$Items[0]['Profit'] //Value = 326
$natureRunePrice // Value = 261
```

This piece of code isn't working correctly:

```
echo $Items[0]['Profit'] - $natureRunePrice;  //result: 326
```

The code is not subtracting these two values for some reason, and I can't figure out why..

There's probably an obvious solution but my PHP is a little rusty so I can't figure out what the problem is here.

UPDATE: [Heres a link to the full code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b48i-af7h)

Comment: What is the exact output from: `var_dump($Items[0]['Profit']);` and `var_dump($natureRunePrice);` ?

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#2519 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "326" } ||AND|| string(44) "261"

Comment: try to cast them with (int) $frist - (int) $second

Comment: Casting didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: is this `var_dump()` just before the echo ? may be `$natureRunePrice` gets modified to `0` in between ?

Comment: var_dump(both values) after that make a new variable where to make the calculation with casting them to int and echo it at the end.. This is full debug way :)

Comment: string(44) "261"?  44 charcters?  var_dump($natureRunePrice); please and echo $natureRunePrice; see if it prints the 261

Comment: @jitendrapurohit No, $natureruneprice is created at the top of the document and never modified again.

Comment: @NickGames Try to trim the second value and casting the first one: `echo (string) $Items[0]['Profit'] - trim($natureRunePrice);`

Comment: Could you please show us the code that defines `$natureRunePrice`

Comment: @Rizier123 Also didn't work...

Comment: @Sugumar Venkatesan still prints 261...

Comment: @NickGames What do you get with: `var_dump(trim($natureRunePrice));` does it still says: `string(44) ..` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, result: string(44) "261"

Comment: Maybe that's because i got the value of $NatureRunePrice off  regex result as you can see in my code. But i wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: @NickGames Then please look at the string in the source code and or with a hex editor, there must be some hidden characters in there.  (+ Copy the real string into your question)

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone! @Rizier123 especially

Comment: @NickGames, take a look at Matei Mihai' answer because what `$matches[0]`returns is something like this `....<span class="GEItem"><span>261......`

Comment: @swidmann yes, that's exactly what i thought ;) And $matches[1] returns the grouped value between the ()

Comment: I just tried this $i=0;
   while($i<45){
    
 echo $natureRunePrice[$i];
 $i++; 
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think that

```
$natureRunePrice = $matches[0];
```

Should be

```
$natureRunePrice = $matches[1];
```

`preg_match` returns the first item in array as the matched string and the other arguments as the saved matching parts

**LATER EDIT**: I read your comments and you confirmed that you've got `261` when var_dumping `$natureRunePrice`. That was happened because you visualized the result in the browser, the result being a string containing html tags which were interpreted by the browser. You could observe the real string length from `string(44) "261"`.

Comment: YES! You're correct! That's where the problem was ;) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So when you take $matches[0]; you get the the whole match? And with $matches[1]; you get the grouped result?

Comment: Depends on how many parts you are trying to save. If you want to save 3 parts in the match then you will have 4 items in the result. To be more clear you can try to run the following code `preg_match('/t(es)(t)/', 'test other', $matches); var_dump($matches);`

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
echo (int)$Items[0]['Profit'] - (int)$natureRunePrice;
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: Indeed, still returns 326